# Analysis Services Error: 'table that is required for a join cannot be reached'

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence

In SSAS I have three dimensions one of which relates to a fact table. When I process the dimension with attributes from each of the other two dimensions I get the above error.

There is definitely a join, between the main dimension and the other two dimensions. The primary key in the same dimension i.e book also relates to the other book foreign keys in the other dimensions.

If I script with two joins it works but SSAS doesn't seem to pick this up.

I have looked at previous posts and tried their recomendation but they are not appropriate for my issue it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Have you refreshed your DSV ? From what i can remember this was usually caused by something going mishap in the DSV, so that the table or view used for the dimension wasn't accessible

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your DSV? Last time I saw this error message, the table relationships were set up incorrectly in the DSV, causing a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to selection of attribute from any other tabale/view instead of related one.

1. Go to dimension structure -> datasource view pane (center pane)
2. Right click and -> show related tables
3. Drag and drop field from table/view .

It should work fine.